Issue with Jackson Deserialization Java
I hope you are well, I have a problem when Jackson deserializes a json.
Context:
I am programming a backend application with Java and Spring boot, where in my controller I request the following object/json:
{
  "ejemFolio": "ABC-123",
  "id": 1,
  "nota": "esto es una nota",
  "idUser": 1
}

Now, in case they send an incorrect data type, such as sending a String in the id fields where an Integer is expected, for example:
{
  "ejemFolio": "ABC-123",
  "id": "un id",
  "nota": "esto es una nota",
  "idUser": "id user"
}

An exception will be thrown, indicating that a problem occurred when deserializing a String into an Integer object. I already handle this exception with an ExceptionHandler:
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<BadRequestResponse> handleBadRequestExceptions(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
Throwable cause = e.getCause();

if (cause instanceof JsonMappingException) {
    JsonMappingException jsonMappingException = (JsonMappingException) cause;
    String fieldName = jsonMappingException.getPath().get(0).getFieldName();
    String message = String.format("Tipo de dato incorrecto para el campo '%s'", fieldName);

    if (cause instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
       InvalidFormatException invalidFormatException = (InvalidFormatException) cause;
       String expectedType = invalidFormatException.getTargetType().getSimpleName();
       String receivedType = invalidFormatException.getValue().getClass().getSimpleName();
       message = String.format("El campo '%s' debe ser de tipo %s, pero se recibió un %s.", fieldName, expectedType, receivedType);
    }
     details.add(message);
}
BadRequestResponse response = new BadRequestResponse(details);

return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

The trouble is the following, that the user receives the following error message:
"El campo 'id' debe ser de tipo Integer, pero se recibio un String"

But only a single field comes, when two fields with incorrect data were sent.
What I would like to do is show all the fields that have incorrect data and that could not be deserialized, in case there are two or three fields, show me in the error message that list with all the fields that were not deserialized. they were able to deserialize.
But here we have another problem, and that is that Jackson throws an exception as soon as it encounters a deserialization error and no longer finishes deserializing all the json. I think this is why it only sends one field in the error message.
I have been researching and I have seen that Jackson has to be configured so that it does not throw an exception as soon as it encounters a deserialization error, but I have not been able to do it, despite trying several codes.
Hoping that it has been understood and if anyone has anything that can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

You are probably looking into validating the json schema bare in mind that this might make your endpoint slow (last time i needed it, not sure if still the case)

You need to create a custom handler to archive what you want to do.
Here is an sample.
public class CustomDeserializationHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {

private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Object handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, String valueToConvert, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
    errors.add(failureMsg);
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object handleWeirdNumberValue(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, Number valueToConvert, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
    errors.add(failureMsg);
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, JsonToken t, JsonParser p, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
    String fieldName = p.getCurrentName();
    String errorMessage = String.format("Invalid format for field '%s': %s (token: %s)", fieldName, failureMsg, t);
    errors.add(errorMessage);
    p.skipChildren(); // Skip the current invalid token
    return null; // Return null to continue processing other fields
}

public List<String> getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

And add this custom handler to ObjectMapper , like this
public static void memberTest(Map<String, Object> source) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CustomDeserializationHandler handler = new CustomDeserializationHandler();
    mapper.addHandler(handler);

    try {
        String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(source);
        Member member = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Member.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> errors = handler.getErrors();
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        errors.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

@Data
public static class Member {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer addr;
}

Beware ObjectMapper is an expensive object.

Sorry but it doesn't work to me :( i don't know if i implement it wrong
